# Gatsby: unique "key" prop

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, contentful

**I'm trying to get a category of data from contentful through Graphql and put out on the web page  but not working right now ..**

**Success**

- Get id, image, slug title

**Fail**

- The only title can not put out on the web page .

**Error**

> index.js:2177 Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique
> "key" prop.
> Blockquote
> Check the render method of `StaticQueryDataRenderer`.

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import { graphql, navigate, StaticQuery } from 'gatsby'
import './home.css'

export default () => (
   <StaticQuery
     query={graphql` 
  query HomeQuery {
    allContentfulBlog(
   
        sort: { fields: [createdAt], order: DESC }     
      ) {
      edges {
        node {
          id
          slug
          title
          category {
            id
           
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`}
     render={data => (
        <div className='feed'>
        {data.allContentfulBlog.edges.map(edge => (
            <div key={edge.node.id} className='card'
        onClick={() => navigate(`/blog/${edge.node.slug}`)} >
        {edge.node.category.map(categories=> (
            <p className='card__category'>{categories.category}</p>
        ))}
        </div>
        ))}
      </div>
     )}
   />
 )
```

Answer (score 1):

As the error shows, it's a `warning`, not an `error`. It won't break your code.

The `key` is a prop that should be provided for all looped items. It is a special string attribute you need to include when creating lists of elements in order to help React identify which items have changed, are added, or are removed. It should be a unique value and it's not a good practice to assign the `index` of the loop (since it's not unique). You can concatenate the index plus another variable (such as the name or title).

You just need to:

```
   {edge.node.category.map( ss => (
        return <p key={ss.title} className='card__category' >{ss.title}</p>
     ))}
```

Spot the `key` and the `return`. All mapped elements must return something.

I would suggest the following readings:

- https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map